# #value error, but works in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

The following function gets a quote from Bloomberg.
The function works, when called from a Sub procedure, but not as a worksheet formula. Does anyone know why?

```
Public Function GetRatesSTATIC() As Variant
   Application.DisplayAlerts = False
   Dim objBK As Workbook
   Dim objRng As Range
   'Open the page as a workbook.
   Set objBK = Workbooks.Open("http://www.bloomberg.com/quote/EURUSD:CUR")
   'Find the Rate
   Set objRng = objBK.Worksheets(1).Cells.Find("EURUSD:CUR")
   'Retrieve the exchange rate.
   GetRatesSTATIC = objRng.Offset(1, 0).Value
   objBK.Close savechanges:=False
   Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Function
```

Comment: It doesn't work as a Formula because with a Formula you do `=FuncTest(A1)` it runs the function provided with the value from `Cell A1` your function doesn't receive anything it only provides back.

Comment: What does it look like when you make it a function? Do you have it taking a value and using it in the macro part?

Comment: @BruceWayne the code you see is the function wether used in VBA only or called as a Formula.  The OP's problem is that he doesn't receive any value because the function doesn't request it while this is mandatory for formula functions

Comment: Ah - I see it now. My eyes aren't awake yet... :P

Comment: Well, if you try to add a variable in the function it is the same #value error. That's why I created the static function without a variable to check what's the problem.

Comment: According to this [knowledge base article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/170787), a limitation of functions is that they cannot "execute most methods", so calling the Workbook.Open method may not be permitted. In my hands your function worked erratically within VBA and not at all when called from a worksheet.

Comment: Thank you, xidgel. It think this is the answer to my question. What was wrong with the vba execution?

Comment: after googling around and also thanks to @xidgel you can't open workbooks with a formula function. An other option is however to do a query and grab the data I tried and tested this with succes.

Comment: Thank you all. Xidgel, Please add your comment as an answer so that I can mark it.

Comment: @Ivo did you want to use a formula or was it purely for testing purposes?

Comment: I intended to use it as formula but now I am going to assign the results to a global variable within the module and do all the calculations in VBA. I only needed 5-6 quotes and it's fine.

Comment: @xidgel, Please add your comment as an answer so that I can mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this [knowledge base article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/170787), a limitation of functions is that they cannot "execute most methods", so calling the Workbook.Open method may not be permitted. In my hands your function worked erratically within VBA and not at all when called from a worksheet.